# What is wrong in this binary search implementation?

Tags: python, binary-search

I have this code:

```
def binary_search(list, item):
    low = 0
    high = len(list)-1
    
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high)/2
        guess = list[mid]
        
        if guess == item:
            return mid
        if guess > item:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid +1
    return None

my_list = [1,3,5,7,9]

print binary_search(my_list, 3)
```

I want the code to perform a binary search of `my_list`, looking for the value `3` and returning its index.

But I get a syntax error from line 19: `print binary_search(my_list, 3)`

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: it should be like this `print(binary_search(my_list, 3))`  you forget open round parethesis!!

Comment: also this should be `mid = (low + high)/2` [float]-> `mid = (low + high)//2` [int]

Comment: `print binary_search(my_list, 3)` - this is python 2 syntax and also you should use integer division '//' when calculating the middle index, regular division returns a float. `mid = (low + high)//2`

Comment: index of list should be int: `mid = int((low + high) / 2)`

Comment: other than that don't use variable name as `list` cause it is one of the data structure in python.!

Comment: If you are learning Python from a Python 2 course, probably switch to one which covers Python 3 instead. Python 2 was end-of-lifed in 2020 and is not worth learning except for very specific scenarios, and even then probably start with Python 3 and then learn the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Making these minor changes will make the code work
1.Use brackets in the print statement 
2."mid" is supplied as an index so it should not be float and be an integer so use "//" for divide
binary_search(list,x)
list -> list of integers
x -> integer whose position is needed

```
def binary_search(list, item): 
  low = 0 
  high = len(list)-1

  while low <= high:
    mid = (low + high)//2
    guess = list[mid]
    
    if guess == item:
        return mid
    if guess > item:
        high = mid - 1
    else:
        low = mid +1
  return None

my_list = [1,3,5,7,9]

print( binary_search(my_list, 3))
```